# Роли для сайта php

Tags: php, mysql

Мне нужно сделать так чтобы определенные ссылки были закрыты для пользователей, но были открыты для админа и модератора. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?php
if ($_SESSION['role'] == '3');
    {
    echo'<a href="admin-panel.php">Админ панель</a>';
    }
else
    {
    echo'<a href="index.php">Вы не админ</a>';
    }
?>
```

ошибка
[Fri Dec 10 10:16:44.529379 2021] [php7:error] [pid 4527] [client 192.168.101.52:53188] PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE), expecting end of file in /var/www/portal.testlab01.local/public_html/cabinet.php on line 44, referer: portal.testlab01.local/kon.php

Comment: поменяйте `=` на `==` а `header` на `echo`.

Comment: Я уже так делал. После перезагрузки сайта пишет это 
[Сейчас эта страница не работает
Сайт portal.testlab01.local сейчас не может обработать этот запрос.
HTTP ERROR 500]

Comment: Загляните в логи - почему 500. Может isset($_SESSION['role']) возвращает false? Когда  вы устанавливаете значения переменной?  Она точно всегда есть? А если пользователь вообще не залогинен???

Comment: [Fri Dec 10 10:16:44.529379 2021] [php7:error] [pid 4527] [client 192.168.101.52:53188] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE), expecting end of file in /var/www/portal.testlab01.local/public_html/cabinet.php on line 44, referer: http://portal.testlab01.local/kon.php

Comment: if ($_SESSION['role'] == '3'); - точка с запетой сдесь не нужна

Comment: начните с того чтобы включить в пхп отображение ошибок

Answer (score 0):

"=" - присвоение значения. В вашем случае `$_SESSION['role'] = '3'` вы присваиваете `$_SESSION['role']` значение `3`. Даная операция всегда будет `true` соответственно всегда будет выполнятся первое условие.

"==" - проверка соответствия. То есть `$_SESSION['role'] == '3'` проверяем или левая часть `$_SESSION['role']` равна `3`. Если равна то будет `true` если нет то `false`.

Так как вам нужно проверить или пользователь может видеть ссылку то вам нужно:
`$_SESSION['role'] == '3' || $_SESSION['role'] == '2'`
но лучше создать глобальный массив с айди ролей которые имеют некий доступ. Например `$CAN_CRUD = ["2", "3"]` - здесь список айди ролей которые могут создавать/читать/редактировать/удалять то есть имеют полный доступ к сайту. Таких массивов можно создать несколько для разного уровня доступа к элементам сайта и потом на страницах проверять и выводить ту или иную информацию. Тогда ваша проверка будет выглядеть `in_array($_SESSION['role'], $CAN_CRUD)`. Проверяем или значение в `$_SESSION['role']` есть в массиве доступов, если есть то получим `true` если нет то `false`.

Тогда ваш код будет выглядеть приблизительно так:

```
$CAN_CRUD = ["2", "3"]
if (in_array($_SESSION['role'], $CAN_CRUD))
{
    echo'<a href="admin-panel.php">Админ панель</a>';
}
else
{
    echo'<a href="index.php">Вы не админ</a>';
}
```

Comment: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: role in /var/www/portal.testlab01.local/public_html/cabinet.php on line 41, referer: http://portal.testlab01.local/index.php

Comment: PHP Warning:  in_array() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in

Comment: вам русским по английски говорят что у вас не объявлена роль "Undefined index: role". Вы точно записываете роль в сессию? Что выводит если сделать `echo $_SESSION['role']`?

Comment: Как сделать запись? Я сейчас перепробовал то что было в инете.

Comment: почитайте документацию по сессиях https://www.php.net/manual/ru/session.examples.basic.php. Общий алгоритм таков, что когда пользователь входит на сайт вы проверяете зарегистрирован ли он и если да то тогда создаете запись в сессии о его роли. Сессия должна быть создана до того как вы отправите заголовки страницы пользователю. То есть сначала создаете запись в сессии и только потом отдаете страницу пользователю. Условно говоря сначала блок с кодом php потом блок с выводом разметки страницы.